# React hooks Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Im trying to map my redux array when the params changed. Its rendering as expected but im getting this error in console. Tried some dependencies on useeffect but cant fix it. Dont know why this happens. Thanks for helps.

Error ;

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
> setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a
> dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

My code ;

```
    const AuthorProfile = () => {
      const params = useParams();
      const posts = useSelector(state => state.redux);
      const [postsArray, setpostsArray] = useState([]);
      const { location, history } = useReactRouter();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (posts.REDUX_POSTS.length) {
          setpostsArray(
            posts.REDUX_POSTS.filter(e => e.authorId === parseInt(params.id)),
          );
        }
      }, [params, posts]);
    
      const openPost = (id) => {
    history.push('/app/posts/read/' + id)
  }

  return (
    <div className="PostContainer">
      <ul className="Posts">
        {postsArray.length &&
          postsArray.map(e => (
            <li key={e.id} onClick={() => openPost(e.id)}>
              <img src={e.image ? e.image : e.authorIcon ? e.authorIcon : 
  NoAuthor} />
              <span className="PostTitle">{e.message}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is `reduxArray`?

Comment: Sorry i edited the post

Comment: I saw the useEffect wworking fine. Please show more component detail

Comment: I added complete code of my component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to maintain redundant state (`postsArray`), it's purely derived state from your redux data. So just compute it. This will additionally help you get rid of the infinite loop caused by the `useEffect` hook.

```
const params = useParams();
const posts = useSelector(state => state.redux);
const { location, history } = useReactRouter();
    
const postsArray = posts.REDUX_POSTS.filter(e => e.authorId === parseInt(params.id));
```